# How to return something from overriden spring mapRow<T> if ResultSet is empty?

Tags: java, spring, resultset

yesterday I got some problems while I tried to return some value from mapRow

```
strings.addAll(getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new RowMapper<String>() {
    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        if(?????????)
            return "--";
        else
            return resultSet.getString("S_PEOPLE_QUANTITY");
        }
    }
));
```

how can I return  for example "--" if my resultSet contains zero rows? what I have2use instead of "?????????" ?

Comment: Do you know how to return something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your data access code should insert custom values like "--" for cases where there is no data. It does not look like good design. The data access code should return a empty list, signifying that there is no data in the data store for the input provided.

Further up in your application, where you want to show "--" for no data available, you should insert a "--" into the list.

Keep the presentation / business logic separate from you data access logic, and the implementation will become easier to develop and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if condition instead of "?????????"

```
if (!resultSet.next()){
// if this condition is true Resultset is empty
}
```

From Java documentation

```
When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned after the last row.
```

Comment: now with !resultSet.next() only "--" elements were returned.. hmmm